# Implement Custom Filtering based on various parameters in Android

Tags: android, filter, android-viewpager, android-filterable, pagertabstrip

I am developing an education based app which lists of subjects and containing courses.
It is implemented using View Pager(which has list of courses in subject) and PagerTabStrip(containing subject name)

class Subject contains List of Courses

```
public class Subject{
       private int id;
       private String name;
       private ArrayList<Course> courses;
    }
```

And class Course containing its own Attributes

```
public class Course {

    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String professorName;
    private String language;
    private boolean isNew;
    private String rating;
    private String imageUrl;
}
```

How to implement filtering based on Subject Name, Course Language, Course Professor Name and Course Rating ?
As in if course language and subject name are the filters then display only those subjects and containing courses as per set filter.

Comment: post your adapter code

Answer (score 0):

Create your adapter class based on filter logic of ArrayList for your Main Tabs and based on that bind your adapter to this PagerTabStrip.

For detailed answer Post your adapter class code or ArrayList example you want to filter.. so, we can help you more..